# How can a human like Yuto or Abe no Seimei live in Magano?

Tags: twin-star-exorcists

In the 16 and 17th episode, we can see that Yuto probably lives in Magano since he appeared out of nowhere and left by jumping around, presumably to his hideout, instead of using Magano Gate directly.

Also, in episode 18, we can see Yuto placing flowers on the Hinatsuki Dorm in Magano, waiting for Rokuro to arrive. This means he *is* somehow, at least, *camping* there.

Also, according to the wiki,

> [Abe no Seimei](http://twin-star-exorcists.wikia.com/wiki/Abe_no_Seimei) is still alive in Magano

Is it possible for humans to 'camp' in Magano? Do humans who pass through the Magano gate not need nourishment?

Comment: Two clarifications: (1) You wrote "in the episode" - which episode? (2) Who is Ichigo? Do you mean the fellow from Bleach?

Comment: Yes a fellow from bleach as example of energy gathering concept / mecahanism

Comment: Clarifications completed. If you believe Bleach spirit particle energy mechanism is off-topic, you may remove it @senshin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact, that Abe no Seimei is still alive in Magano, was just barely mentioned in manga, and there was no real proof for that.

Nevertheless, in ch. 17 of manga, it was shown, that exorcist may survive really long time without any supplies, based only on his divine powers. So, I suppose, the strongest exorcist in history may stay alive in Magano for really long time.

Regarding Yuto, question is slightly incorrect, since according to ch. 13,

> Yuto is no longer human anymore, he is much more like Basara being - he infected himself with Impurity, and managed to gain control over it.

Comment: Well he does mention about Onmyouji is human who can control Yin and Yang.. and Basara can use dark talisman. Also, Yuto 'transform' himself to Basara using some talisman that is usable by human, a young human even. I believe Abe no Seimei can also control Yin and Yang (of course) thus being some sort of 'natural' basara onmyodo creature. Note that Kuranashi had to kidnap a lot of Onmyouji to make a good talisman, and Yuto can make good talisman himself, so Yuto should be in similar situation to the Abe no Seimei, who is born from a Fox (ayakashi? kegare? bad talisman?) and a human (good tals)

Answer (score 0):

Because he was born there. His mother is Abe no Seimei. But I think he is the light side of her. And she only gave birth to him to destroy her at the end.